# Angular ng build --target=production giving errors

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, production

I have a created a new Angular Project using Angular-CLI.

The versions I am using are:

Angular-Cli: 1.0.2

Angular: 4.0.0.

I have added a lot of code in it but now, when I build my project using below command I get bunch of errors

`ng build --target=production --env=staging`

Errors:

> /src/app/views/signup/signup.component.html (21,86): Property 'email' is protected and only accessible within class 'SignUpComponent' and its subclasses.
>
> /src/app/views/signup/signup.component.html (26,80): Property 'password' is protected and only accessible within class 'SignUpComponent' and its subclasses.

Can someone please help me in this regard that how can I remove these errors? The build is successful when I omit `--target=production` BUT in past I got issue that without specifying target browser cache the old deployment version and user has to delete the browser cache to effect latest changes/deployment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are your email and password properties defined to be private? Are they used in the component's template? Then they need to be changed from private to public.

When you use the Angular CLI's production mode, you automatically get the following:

- `--aot` is set to true
- `--output-hashing` is set to all (fingerprints assets)
- `--sourcemaps` is set to false
- `--extract-css` is set to true (makes real css files for global styles, while dev makes .js files as a rebuild optimization)
- adds service worker if configured in the CLI json
- replaces `process.env.NODE_ENV` in modules with the `production` value (this is needed for some libs, like react)
- runs uglify on the code

See this for more information: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/6232

It is the aot compiler that is most likely generating these errors. The aot compiler compiles the template in TypeScript and hence generates more type errors. So another alternative is to use the `--prod` without aot.

Comment: Yes, the email and password are protected in the component's but in previous version of angular-cli/angular it worked. So, should I make them public or use --aot=false?

Comment: Make them Public... AOT is necessary for production performance

Comment: I'm not sure as to which version of the CLI started to turn --aot to true for production mode. But my guess is that is why it worked previously. And as P. Moloney mentioned ... using --aot=false is not really a good choice because the aot (ahead of time compiler) can improve your startup performance.

Answer (score 2):

You cloud try to set public visibility on email and password.