# Web pack build error on prod mode - angular4

Tags: angular

Is there any reason why building the angular application using production mode gives lot of error ?

When i ran my application using ng build, it doesn't show any error. when i build the same using below command, I am getting many error

1) private property error 
2) Method not found in component

```
ng build --target=production --environment=prod
```

Any reason ?

Comment: yes, I think its because angular tries to optimize your code and remove unnecessary parts, so it analyze your code more in depth then if you "simply" build it for debugging...

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43932667/1009922) and at the "Common Mistakes" section in [this article](https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-writing-aot-friendly-applications-7b64c8afbe3f).

Comment: Thanks ConnorsFan, That likened helped me to understand what is happening ..